# How to set null value from SQL query to empty string in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to query array of strings from SQL using this code:

```
defaultMail = getDefaultMailList(requester);
```

and the sql query string is

```
SELECT * FROM dbo. ....
```

Then, I get array of string from the `getDefaultMailList` method:

```
string toEmail = defaultMail[0];
string ccEmail = defaultMail[1];
```

Then, I use the value of SQL query to make a condition of if else like this.

```
if (ccEmail != "")
{
    do something
}
```

Now, I met the problem when SQL query returns `null` value. The `ccList != ""` still returns `TRUE`, but I want to make it return `FALSE`.

How to handle with this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: use `isnull` funtion in your column. Like `select isnull(Somecolumn,'') Somecolumn from sometable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if it's empty or null you can use the [`IsNullOrEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netcore-3.1) Function. This function will both check if the variable is null or empty.

If you want to check user input you could also use [`IsNullOrWhitespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netcore-3.1), which additionally checks if the string consists of only whitespace characters.

```cs
// Check if the string is either empty or null.
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccList))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ccList)` also can be used and this will check for whitespaces too

Comment: Just wanted to add that :D.